# How to sort notepad data in average order?

Tags: python, sorting, average

```
elif how == 3:
        with open("Class1.txt") as f:
            def score(line):
                return float(line.split(',')[1])
            for line in f:
                string_of_numbers = []
                print('Total ', (len(string_of_numbers)))
                print('Average ',sum(string_of_numbers)/(len(string_of_numbers)))
```

I have this so far but what I want is for it to print my data with each name with their average score beside it.

This is what **Class1.txt** looks like:

```
Ben, 10 
John, 4 
Billy, 9
Torin, 10
Charlie, 2
Celyn, 5
Ben, 5
John, 1
Billy, 5
Torin, 5
Charlie, 6
Celyn, 2
Ben, 6
John, 9
Billy, 5 
Torin, 4 
Charlie, 9
Celyn, 1
```

Comment: Please show the content of `Class1.txt`.

Comment: Are all names on one line or is each name value pair on a separate line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to collect all values per name:

```
with open("Class1.txt") as fobj:
    scores = {}
    for line in fobj:
        name, score = line.split(',')
        name = name.strip()
        score = int(score)
        scores.setdefault(name, []).append(score)
```

Now, print out the results:

```
for name, values in scores.items():
    print(name, 'Total: {} Average: {:5.2f} '.format(
          len(values), sum(values) / (len(values))))
```

prints:

```
John Total: 3 Average:  4.67 
Ben Total: 3 Average:  7.00 
Charlie Total: 3 Average:  5.67 
Celyn Total: 3 Average:  2.67 
Torin Total: 3 Average:  6.33 
Billy Total: 3 Average:  6.33
```

Comment: Thank you but I get a error saying that "fobj" is bad. What do i do?